# .Net Core Swagger documentation yields 404 when adding SwaggerDoc

Tags: .net-core, swagger

This evening I'm running into the weirdest of issues when trying to configure Swagger in my .NET 6 application. The interesting code looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // --- Code that used to go in Startup.ConfigureService --- 
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
    
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
        options =>
        {
            //options.SwaggerDoc("Foobar", new OpenApiInfo(){Title = "Some title"});
        });
    
    
    var app = builder.Build();

    // --- Code that used to go in Startup.Configure --- 
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Some title"));


    // --- Run the application --- 
    app.Run();
}
```

When I debug the application, the Swagger page is shown correctly and I can see the controller methods etc. However, if I on line 5 add `options.SwaggerDoc(...)` (now commented out), the Swagger page shows a popup with the text "response status is 404 /swagger/v1/swagger.json".
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default url for getting generated document is `http[s]://localhost:<port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json` and for UI is `https://localhost:<port>/swagger`. but when you add this line:

```
options.SwaggerDoc("Foobar", new OpenApiInfo(){Title = "Some title"});
```

And the pattern of url is:

```
http[s]://localhost:<port>/swagger/{swaggerDocName}/swagger.json
```

So you need to change this line :

```cs
 app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Foobar/swagger.json", "Some title"));
```